# No Wifi Adapter found Ubuntu 20 LTS Legion Y7000

Tags: drivers, wireless, lenovo, adapter

first off, i apologize if this question has been asked before, but i've been running through all forums and tried all suggestions with no luck.
i newly installed ubuntu 20 LTS on my Lenovo Legion Y7000 and everything was working perfectly up until i did an `apt upgrade`.
now it cannot even detect the wifi adapter
at first, the `rfkill list` was not even showing the wifi, but after some commands (i cant remember which at this point) it is now showing as soft blocked.

this is the result of `lspci`:
`Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8822BE 802.11a/b/g/n/ac WiFi adapter (rev ff)`

`lshw -C network` shows only the ethernet connection i have

i also tried `sudo apt-get install --reinstall bcmwl-kernel-source` with no luck

not sure if this helps, but this is the content of my `/etc/modprobe.d/`:

```
alsa-base.conf                  blacklist-modem.conf
amd64-microcode-blacklist.conf  blacklist-oss.conf
blacklist-ath_pci.conf          blacklist-rare-network.conf
blacklist-bcm43.conf            dkms.conf
blacklist.conf                  intel-microcode-blacklist.conf
blacklist-firewire.conf         iwlwifi.conf
blacklist-framebuffer.conf      r8822be.conf
```

also this is the output of `lsusb`:

```
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 13d3:56a6 IMC Networks Integrated Camera
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0bda:b023 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. Bluetooth Radio 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3`:

```
07:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8822BE 802.11a/b/g/n/ac WiFi adapter [10ec:b822]
    Subsystem: Lenovo ThinkPad E595 [17aa:b023]
    Kernel driver in use: rtw_pci
    Kernel modules: rtwpci, wl, rtw_8822be
```

output of `rfkill list`:

```
0: ideapad_wlan: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no
1: ideapad_bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
2: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

output of `dmesg | grep rtw`:

```
[    2.821119] rtw_core: module verification failed: signature and/or required key missing - tainting kernel
[    2.835511] rtw_pci 0000:07:00.0: Firmware version 27.2.0, H2C version 13
[    2.835543]  ? rtw_mac_power_on+0x2fd/0x460 [rtw_core]
[    2.835545]  rtw_chip_info_setup+0x123/0x680 [rtw_core]
[    2.835548]  rtw_pci_probe+0x524/0x880 [rtwpci]
[    2.835568]  rtw_pci_driver_init+0x23/0x1000 [rtwpci]
[    2.835593] Modules linked in: rtwpci(+) snd_seq_midi rtw_8822b(OE) snd_seq_midi_event rtw_8723d(OE) rtw_8822c(OE) snd_rawmidi rtw_core(OE) aesni_intel(+) nvidia(PO+) mei_hdcp intel_rapl_msr uvcvideo(+) btusb snd_seq fjes(-) crypto_simd mac80211 btrtl videobuf2_vmalloc cryptd i915(+) videobuf2_memops btbcm videobuf2_v4l2 btintel glue_helper snd_seq_device bluetooth snd_timer videobuf2_common cfg80211 input_leds(+) videodev intel_cstate ecdh_generic intel_wmi_thunderbolt wmi_bmof intel_rapl_perf serio_raw ipmi_devintf 8250_dw libarc4 mc snd ecc hid_multitouch(+) drm_kms_helper ipmi_msghandler processor_thermal_device i2c_algo_bit mei_me soundcore fb_sys_fops syscopyarea mei intel_rapl_common sysfillrect intel_soc_dts_iosf ucsi_acpi sysimgblt intel_pch_thermal typec_ucsi mac_hid typec ideapad_laptop int3403_thermal int340x_thermal_zone sparse_keymap int3400_thermal acpi_thermal_rel acpi_pad sch_fq_codel parport_pc ppdev lp parport drm ip_tables x_tables autofs4 hid_generic crc32_pclmul ahci
```

finally, i tried to format the pc again and reinstall the OS since wifi was working before the upgrade, but that as well is not working anymore...

thank you so much for your help

Comment: Hm ... the driver is crashing. This is a bug in the driver or kernel.

Comment: @Pilot6 is it possible to find another driver for it or something?

Answer (score 0):

You need to install drivers for rtl8822be.

Run in a terminal:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install git dkms
git clone https://github.com/lwfinger/rtw88.git
sudo dkms add ./rtw88
sudo dkms install rtlwifi-new/0.6
```

Probably previously you installed a driver without using `dkms`. So it didn't build on a kernel update.

I suggest to remove the `/etc/modprobe.d/r8822be.conf` file.

Secure Boot should be disabled in BIOS.

Comment: everything installed with no errors. wifi still not working. i removed the ```/etc/modprobe.d/r8822be.conf``` and secure boot is disabled

Comment: Please add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list; dmesg | grep rtw` terminal command to your question.

Comment: alright, updated my question

Answer (score 0):

Alright, to explain what was happening, based on the logs i got from `journalctl -b | grep rtl` i found out that the driver is crashing on boot.
after i did some research it turns out, blocking the bluetooth driver will solve it (small sacrifice for a great victory). perhaps this is not the ideal solution, not until an update comes up with a bug fix for this.

the way to do this, is going into `/etc/modprob.b/blacklist.conf` and adding the following lines:

```
blacklist btrtl 
blacklist btusb
```

then reboot and my problem was solved at long last